# Displaying multiple fields in referenced webform option?

Tags: views, 8, webforms

First I have a content type **Quiz option** which represents one option (answer) for a webform question (field).

Then I have a (entity reference) view which is collecting specific number of nodes in this type. I got one argument to that view, which represents question id and when passed I'm getting all possible answers for that question.

And then I got a webform, where I have field of **entity checkbox** type where all options are referenced with that view. So webform field options are set like:

```
Type of item to reference: Content
Reference method: Views: Filter by an entity reference view
View used to select the entities: my view
View arguments: that question id
```

And all this works well - I'm getting the possible options from that view and as option titles node titles are displayed.

Basically if I create new node in "Quiz option" and select for it question id i.e. 1 then view referencing those node will also display it when question id 1 is passed and since question in my webform is using that view new option will appear as a new option under that option.

Now what I need is to display another field (image field) beside that title as part of an webform option. I've added image field to my content type. Then I adjusted my view so it also displays the image. But problem is that webform is still displaying only node title. New image field is ignored. Checked on "Display options" of my content type, but image field is not hidden there. So must be that webform module is responsible - it's displaying only referenced node title no matter what used view is returning.

Is there a way do configure my webform field to display this extra field for field options instead of only node titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from Drupal core and is fixed in Drupal 8.8.

@see [Issue #2174633: View output is not used for entityreference options](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2174633)

Comment: Drupal 8.8 will be release in 2 days, so I'll have to wait.

Comment: Updated. It works now!